# How long does mana from Burning-Tree Emissary stay around?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does mana added to your pool from [Burning-Tree Emissary](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Burning-Tree%20Emissary) get destroyed when the card that added it is destroyed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mana created by [Burning-Tree Emissary](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Burning-Tree%20Emissary) is no different than then mana created by [Forest](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Forest) and [Mountain](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mountain) cards. Keep in mind the ability of a Forest reads "{T}: Add {G} to your mana pool."

As usual, it remains there until used or until the current step or phase ends.

> 500.4. When a step or phase ends, any unused mana left in a player’s mana pool empties. This turn-based action doesn’t use the stack.

Comment: Thanks!  I was thinking it was too easy to gain two free mana for the whole game

Comment: @ikegami, But since there's no mana burn now, doesn't this mean that the penalty it used to have is no longer there?

Comment: @Parcerier, Correct. By following the link in the answer, you can see it has not receive any errata. The whole point of removing mana burn was to simplify the game by removing a rule that had little effect on the game. (I'll dig up the announcement if you ask me to.) Recreating the rule through an errata would have been counter-productive.